What block cipher mode of operation is "ECB w/VCC"?
L3Harris lists “ECB w/VCC” as a supported AES mode of operation for some of their devices.
There seems to be no information on such a mode of operation on the Internet.
What could “ECB w/VCC” mean and does it ensure semantic security?


This query locates this with "VMware and the vCenter
Console Server (VCC)". Your guess from there is as good as mine. This is not an aswer!

It might be Variable Code Chaining, ask them.
